# How do you test Rails helpers which accepts a block with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, block, helper

Given the following RSpec test:

```
  context "items" do
    it "should be able to place links in an expandable menu" do
      output = helper.button("Hello", '#') do
        self.content << helper.item("Test", "example.org")
      end.should include "Test"
    end
  end
```

And the following helper:

```
 def button(name, url, options = {}, &block)
    if block_given?
      content = with_output_buffer(&block)
      content_tag(:li, :class => 'expandable menu-item') do
        concat link_to(content_tag(:span, name), url, options)
        concat content_tag :div, content, :class => :box
      end
    else
      return content_tag :li, link_to(content_tag(:span, name), url, options), :class => :button
    end
  end
```

This helper is supposed to create a button and an expandable menu once clicked if a block is given to the button helper.

Example View:

```
= menu do
  = button("Test", '#') do
    %h1 Hello you!
```

Produces:

```
<li class="expandable menu-item"><a href="#"><span>Test</span></a><div class="box"><h1>Hello you!</h1>
```

Exactly what I expected! Once I try out the RSpec test it fails and upon further inspected it seems nothing is being yielded within the

```
<div class="box">...</div>
```

RSpec output:

```
expected "<li class=\"expandable menu-item\"><a href=\"#\"><span>Hello</span></a><div class=\"box\"></div></li>" to include "Test"
```

I've tried raising content inside if block_given? after content = with_output_buffer(&block) and it is indeed empty. I must be doing something wrong in my test as to why it's empty.

Help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, i'll try :-)

do you have any particular reason to use `with_output_buffer` instead of `capture`?

You can take look at the `capture` source: `..../gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb` and you will see that it is using `with_output_buffer` in a different way that you are using it.

The gist is that `capture` can work with blocks that returns string. So with that you can simply use:

```
it "should work" do
  helper.button("Hello", "#") do
    "test"
  end.should include "test"
end
```

**UPDATE:** Ah I forgot to mention that it will work when you change your code from:

```
content = with_output_buffer(&block)
```

to

```
content = capture(&block)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It seems to work with capture. I'll have a look in the source of capture and see what it does.